# Are there any government policies that meaningfully influence mass shootings per capita?

Tags: united-states, guns, second-amendment

Which states have the most mass shootings per capita? Which states have the least?

**Mass Shooting**:  FOUR or more shot and/or killed in a single event [incident], at the same general time and location  not including the shooter.

Are there any government policies that meaningfully influence these rates, or does it appear to be random?

Comment: To make this an on topic question the appropriate addition might be: "Are there any government policies that meaningfully influence these rates, or does it appear to be random?"

Comment: I've observed worldwide a correlation between wealth inequality and homicide rate, as well as an inverse correlation between education and homicide rate.  It is likely that states with high levels of poverty and poor education likely have more mass shootings per capita.  There are no reliable gun ownership statistics; but if there were, you could probably find a correlation between high gun ownership and high mass shooting rates.  Also note: the Small Arms Survey is the most often cited gun stat source, but it is unreliable.

Comment: @John Actually there is a negative correlation between gun ownership and homicide rate. The more guns, the less the homicide rate. I would assume mass shootings are counted as homicides. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fkhJz1USHrwu3k0FMRKVHNqEJunPB0Bj4IZ9yGzNNfY/edit#gid=1952426520 Why is Small Arms Survey unreliable?

Comment: @Chloe See the criticisms section of the Small Arms Survey wikipedia article.  Also, you can't compute a correlation between gun ownership and homicide rate if you don't actually have accurate data on how many citizens own guns, so the claim of negative correlation is unsubstantiated.  Also, correlation should be computed based on how many citizens own guns, not how many guns per citizen.  If there are 112.6 guns per 100 citizens in the U.S., then what percent of Americans own guns?  112.6%?  No.  What percent?  You don't know.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Arms_Survey#Criticism

Comment: @John It looks like they updated it in 2017 and Finland is now at 32.4 per 100 residents. I criticize the criticism because it didn't state the actual number the critics believe is true. It's not constructive. The criticism also states that every family must have an illegal firearm to be true, but it doesn't consider that some families may have multiple firearms, the same criticism that you gave. So unless I see different stats, I'm likely to continue believing it. Yes, having % citizens who own guns would be more useful.

Comment: @John Another criticism of the criticism I have is the nitpicking fallacy. They only pick 1 country and claim the whole data is corrupt, but there are 175 countries.

Comment: @Chloe does your spreadsheet correlate the actual civilian gun ownership rate with homicide rate?  It should be transparently obvious to anyone that it does not.  What percent of Americans own guns?  Is that the same number that is in your spreadsheet?  There are other studies that estimate that 36.1% of Americans own guns.  Your spreadsheet says 112.6%.  It seems like you're not even trying to use an intellectually honest statistic.  Also, there have been a lot of studies which draw the opposite conclusion.  https://www.vox.com/2016/2/29/11120184/gun-control-study-international-evidence

Comment: @John It is clearly labeled `Guns per 100 Residents (2014)` and it does not say `%`. That study conflates homicides with suicides. Talk about intellectually dishonest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82892/discussion-between-john-and-chloe).

Comment: @CramerTV - yes, you are right, but the old question was offtopic (not about politics of government) and also this was the last question in the OP. I will let Chloe decide what is the actual question in the post.

Comment: The question is tagged United States, but it isn't mentioned in the text of the question. Are you only interested in the US, or does incidents like Port Arthur in Australia or Christchurch in NZ count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC, Louisiana, and Illinois have the most, and Hawaii, Idaho, New Hampshire, North Dakota, and Wyoming had the least (none) in the 2014 to May 1st, 2017 period.

[image: Mass shootings per capita by state]

Source: http://www.gunviolencearchive.org/reports, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population

[Excel sheet on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XPKIrgZLLuaDduUWwwZVBjNFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please define "mass shooting" as used by the gun violence archive.

Comment: This is an utterly useless statistic, because the rate of occurrence is so low.

Comment: It;s also somewhat useless for many other reasons (e.g. "Illinois" is not a uniform place; neither are others).

Comment: @DrunkCynic Added the definition in the question.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian https://twitter.com/Wu_Tang_Finance/status/857005051964948480

Comment: @user4012 Gun laws vary by state. The gun laws are generally uniform throughout the state.

Comment: @Chloe - nope, sorry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_laws_in_Illinois#Local_laws

Comment: @Chloe Consider researching the nature of preemption. http://smartgunlaws.org/gun-laws/policy-areas/other-laws/local-authority/

Comment: This answer is no longer complete due to recent changes to the question. The current version of the question focuses on correlation between government policies and mass shooting rates, more than geographic distribution of mass shootings.

Comment: This graph could benefit from some error bars.